# How to query last login time of each user?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have indexes of user informations. 
Each document stores the login information 
It has two field user name and login time.

Every time a user logs in, a document will be saved as below.
For example,

```
{
"userName": "tom",
"loginTime": "2019-02-27 07:00:00"
}
```

So, I want to find out last login time of each user. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Every time a user logs in, a document will be saved? Does this mean that there will multiple documents for a given user? You want find out last login for every user or for given user/set of users?

Comment: will the same doc be overwritten or a new doc would be inserted, also are you not keeping some unique user id?. you need to state the problem statement clearly.